# PHP loop array continuesly every nth value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a loop to loop through an array with x amount of items or values of an array:

```
$count = 4;
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10);
```

I want to loop this 90 times for example and get every `$count = 4;` element continuously so for the first 5 times it'll be as follows:

```
4
8
2
6
10
```

and so-on for 90 times or whatever number I set it to.
If you guys have any idea, or guidance to a previews post because I may not be working my search correctly, Please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So show us the code you have tried

Comment: do you want 90 results or iterate over the Array 90 times ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo i want to Iterate 90 times, Jakub wrona codes work. but cant it be modify to work with strings not only numbers?

Comment: so you want 90 results in total, i will update my answer, take a look, it should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < ($count*$numberOfResults); $i += $count){
   echo $array[$i%count($array)];
}
```

Something like this ?

Comment: Oh wow i made a typo, i bet you never did ...
neverless it is the only answer here without hardcoded values, and should work perfectly fine. And $i < $iterations * Count($Array) was for the case that he wants to iterate 90 times over the whole Array, not only 90 results.

Comment: Actually that does not produce 90 results, so you might like to test it

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo the code loops through `$numberOfResults` but since its doing the `$count` it gives me less results not the 90 results.

Comment: ups, okay this wasn't the case on the downvote, but it is now, and i belive for this one i earned the downvote. Altougth it should have been possible to fix that by your own. Corrected it. @user2444411

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo this works, and produces the 90 results thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=90; $i++) {
    echo (($i*4%10) == 0) ? '10' : ($i*4%10);
    echo "\n";
}
```

I am sure you could change the snippet yourself a bit to fit your needs, but if you can't:

```
$fruits = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
for ($i=1; $i<=90; $i++) {
    $element = (($i*4%10) == 0) ? '10' : ($i*4%10);
    echo $fruits[$element-1];
    echo "\n";
}
```

A quick explanation: arrays are indexed starting from 0 so the above 10 letters are indexed 0..9 - that's why you have to do $element-1

Comment: this works, can you modify it to work with an array such as `$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana' );`

Comment: You have _fallen into the rabbit hole_. I hope you are now prepared to do all the OP's homework